# Editing a huge file - Vim or something else?

Tags: linux, vim

- I am Vim fan for most of my editing purposes.
- But these days when I have to open huge file ~1-2 gigs, its is vert slow to load and perform operations
- What are the other ways I can edit such huge files efficiently

Comment: Turn off syntax can make vim run a little faster.

Comment: In my experience loading a big file like that takes some time, but once it is loaded Vim is actually pretty fast.

Comment: You can always use `sed`.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159521/text-editor-to-open-big-giant-huge-large-text-files

Answer (score 6):

vim you can

> :set binary

first.

or use hexedit. as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699785/edit-very-large-sql-dump-text-file-on-linux

Answer (score 3):

Set

```
:syntax off
:se binary nospell 
:setgl noswap
:set undolevel=0
:set undofile=
```

You can also use `directory`/`undodir` to put swapfiles and undofiles in another location

Answer (score 3):

Look here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/28847/text-editor-to-open-4-3-gb-plain-text-file

- Divide the file in parts : `split -b 53750k <your-file>`
- Edit sigle parts with vim ( I don't like it but it works fast here )
- Merge the parts `cat xa* > <your-file>`

Done :)

Sorry but free editor larks good support for big files ( cannot find a reason for that )

p.s.
learn Vim is not so difficult:
http://yannesposito.com/Scratch/en/blog/Learn-Vim-Progressively/

Comment: I had to change the merge command a little bit since I had such a large file that after xaz came xba so xa* would have left out the ones starting with xb. I didn't have any other files starting with x in the same directory so I just used x*. Just in case someone runs into any issues using these commands.

Answer (score 0):

Try [joe](http://joe-editor.sourceforge.net/). I just used it to edit a ~5G SQL dump file. It took about a minute to open the file and a few minutes to save it, with very little use of swap (on a system with 4G RAM).